# Audio Source object reference not set to instance of an object in Unity.

Tags: unity, audio

I have the following script:

```
public class soundcontrol : MonoBehaviour {
    AudioSource theaudio ;
    public AudioClip clip1;
    public AudioClip clip2;
    public AudioClip clip3;
    AudioClip[] cliparray;
    int currentclip = -1;
    int maxclip = 0;
    bool isclip1null = false;
    bool isclip2null = false;
    bool isclip3null = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        maxclip = 0;
        if (clip1 != null) {
            isclip1null = true;
            cliparray [maxclip] = clip1;
            maxclip = maxclip + 1;
        }
        if (clip2 != null) {
            isclip2null = true;
            cliparray [maxclip] = clip2;
            maxclip = maxclip + 1;
        }
        if (clip3 != null) {
            isclip3null = true;
            cliparray [maxclip] = clip3;
            maxclip = maxclip + 1;
        }
        if (!theaudio.isPlaying) { // the error is here
            if (!((maxclip - 1) == -1)) {
                currentclip = currentclip + 1;
                if (currentclip > maxclip) {
                    currentclip = 0;
                }
                if (!((maxclip - 1) == -1)) {
                    theaudio.PlayOneShot (cliparray [currentclip]);
                }
            }
        }
        if ((maxclip - 1) == -1) {
            Debug.Log (" no clip attached ");
        }
    }
}
```

The error was at `theaudio.isPlaying` checking, the method I use is the same as what's in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html).

So, why is this thing happening? The documentation is just too bad to be understood (they can use that magic while I can't).

I also have audio source attached.

I'm a beginner with Unity so before you guys downvote please help me solve my problem first, and I'm sorry if this has already been asked somewhere, Google just seems to not give me the answer I want :\

Comment: i wrongly put some part but that not solve the problem , editing post .

Comment: You don't seem to initialize `cliparray` in any way...

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt , there is already part where its checked ( also not giving error in the log ) , the error i asking now is only audio source

Comment: You don't seem to initialize `theaudio` in any way...

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt i already said ... in the documentation its work , then how can i initialize it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error *"object not set to an instance of an object"* means that you're trying to use an object that is null (NullReferenceException). When you get that error, the first thing to do is to isolate *which* object/access is generating the error, then to trace back if that object is effectively initialized, and then make sure it's properly initialized before using it.

There is a more complete explanation on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779184/637987).

In your specific case, you need to initialize the `audioSource` object before you can use it.

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-isPlaying.html) about the method you're trying to use is quite explicit on how you do that: you set up the `audioSource` in the `start` function by getting the appropriate component.

```
// When the audio component has stopped playing, play otherClip
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip otherClip;
    AudioSource audio;

    void Start() {
      audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (!audio.isPlaying) {
            audio.clip = otherClip;
            audio.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can i use this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>() ?

Comment: @user6668201 Why would you want to do that?

Comment: for different object

Comment: @user6668201 I've never tried, but I guess you could. Not sure about the exact syntax, though.

Comment: i mean , i only need to drag and drop the script whenever i want to create new object with different clip

Comment: uh error and error come again ..... thanks for solution anyway

Comment: @user6668201 Maybe [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-clip.html) is what you're after?